# select child element with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get some element from html below but i didn't have success.
I am trying to append some `li` into `.istasyon-listele` which is child of `.havalimani`

I tried this `$('#location-info .havalimani>.istasyon-listele')` didn't help me.
I also tried `$('#location-info .havalimani .istasyon-listele')` didn't help too.

If i try to select `.isim`  I can make it with `$('#location-info .isim')` it works for me. But others are not.

```
<div class="location-info" id="location-info"  style="position: absolute;z-index:9999999; display:none;">
            <ul class="location-name">
                <li class="havalimani">
                    <h5  class="havalimanih5"> Havalimanı Şubeleri</h5>
                    <ul class="istasyon-liste">
                        <li>asdada</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="sehirici">
                    <h5 class="sehiricih5">Şehiriçi Şubeleri</h5>

                    <ul class="istasyon-liste">
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="detail-info visible-lg visible-md" id="1">
                <div class="detail-info-contact">
                    <h5 class="isim">Kusadasi</h5>
                    <p class="adres">Ataturk Bulvari</p>

                    <ul id="bilgiler">
                        <li class="telefon">Telefon : <span></span></li>
                        <li class="haftaici">Hafta içi : <span class="hici"></span></li>
                        <li class="cumartesi">Cumartesi : <span class="hsonu"></span></li>
                        <li>Pazar : <span class="pazar"></span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <style>
                    .detail-info-contact {
                        margin-bottom:0;
                    }
                    .detail-info-contact ul {
                        text-align: left;
                        text-indent: 7px;
                    }
                    .detail-info-contact ul li {
                        font-size: 11px;
                        padding: 0 5px 0 0;
                        vertical-align: top;
                    }
                </style>


                <div class="googlemap" class="map-canvas">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

So i cannot append any li element into $('#location-info .havalimani>.istasyon-liste')
For example, i tried this:

```
$('#location-info .havalimani>.istasyon-liste').append('<li>something</li>');
```

Did not effect.

But if i log the $('#location-info .havalimani>.istasyon-liste') i can see "asdada"

Comment: Your code doesn't have any element with the class `.istasyon-listele` Is it a typo?

Comment: @Dekel Yes i have. im sorry but my problem is different may i edit here or create new question?

Comment: Edit here, it is much better. No need to open new question for every small change :)

Comment: But i think question is not small change but anyway i am editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
      .detail-info-contact {
        margin-bottom:0;
      }
      .detail-info-contact ul {
        text-align: left;
        text-indent: 7px;
      }
      .detail-info-contact ul li {
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 0 5px 0 0;
        vertical-align: top;
     }
   </style>
 </head>
<body>
  <div class="location-info" id="location-info" >
   <ul class="location-name">
    <li class="havalimani">
        <h5  class="havalimanih5"> Havalimanı Şubeleri</h5>
        <ul class="istasyon-liste">
            <li>asdada</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="sehirici">
        <h5 class="sehiricih5">Şehiriçi Şubeleri</h5>

        <ul class="istasyon-liste">
        </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>
   <div class="detail-info visible-lg visible-md" id="1">
    <div class="detail-info-contact">
        <h5 class="isim">Kusadasi</h5>
        <p class="adres">Ataturk Bulvari</p>
        <ul id="bilgiler">
            <li class="telefon">Telefon : <span></span></li>
            <li class="haftaici">Hafta içi : <span class="hici"></span></li>
           <li class="cumartesi">Cumartesi:<span class="hsonu"></span> </li>        
            <li>Pazar : <span class="pazar"></span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script src="js/jquery_2.1.4.min.js"></script>
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

      var link = $("<li>", {
     "text":"I'm a new link!",
     "css":{"background":"yellow"}
     });
   // or if you prefer : var link = "<li>something</li>"
   $('li.havalimani').find("ul.istasyon-liste").append(link);
  });
   </script>
</body>
```

I have tested and it adds a li to the inner ul .